# По какому принципу устанавливается значение int полей в классе R в Andriod Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Например в проекте в классе `R.anim` первое поле:

```
public static final int abc_fade_in= 0x7f010000;
```

Далее значение каждого следующего поля это значение предыдущего + 1.

Почему начинается со значения 0x7f010000, а не какого-то другого числа?

В [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R) про это ничего не говорится.

Нашел подобный [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43938671/7310823) и там есть [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43939065/7310823) от [gokcand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4515361/gokcand), к сожалению без какой-либо ссылки на источник.

Comment: Мне кажется, что все числа ниже зарезервированы под системные значения.